# Caliburn.Micro IChild.Parent is null unless activated by conductor

Tags: c#, .net, caliburn.micro

I have a Parent and Child viewmodel:

```
public class ParentViewModel : Screen 
{
    public ChildViewModel Child { get; set; }
}

public class ChildViewModel  : PropertyChangedBase, IChild { }
```

When the Parent VM is displayed using `Conductor.ActivateItem()`, Caliburn.Micro does the usual labours of searching through the view model object graph and looking for views to display etc.

After all this is completed, I find that while `ParentViewModel.Parent` is a reference to the Conductor, `ChildViewModel.Parent` is `null`.

Is this by design?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is by design, the method that sets the `Parent` property is `EnsureItem` in the `ConductorBase`, therefore it's only conductors that will set it when the active item is changed.

The `Parent` is therefore also only available in the activation life cycle of the child, e.g. `OnInitialise` or `OnActivate` etc.

Is there any reason your `ParentViewModel` isn't a `Conductor` type and your `ChildViewModel` a Screen?

Also, depending on the `Parent` property may be introducing coupling in your `ChildViewModel`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's not a conductor because it's not conducting various sub-screens. The child is really just a complex datatype so that I can have a composed UI. I can set the parent myself for now. I need it set because I have a `ShowDialog` IResult that walks up the parents until it finds something I call an `IDialogConductorHost` and asks it's `DialogConductor` to display the dialog. It's how I ensure all my dialogs appear on the same "layer". If the `Parent` property is null, the chain is broken and `ShowDialog` can't get to the dialog conductor.

Comment: I see. Presumably you must be using a static factory method and passing in the instance of the child? Could the parent not inject a factory type into the child which creates the IResult type? The factory type could then take the specific dialog conductor host that needs to be used in that context.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround for this is for the parent VM to pass itself to the child VM somehow.

Either by setting the `Parent` property explicitly:

```
var child = new ChildViewModel
{
    Parent = this
};
```

Or, assuming you have some sort of IoC-based abstraction for initialising view model objects, you could have a convention of implementing `Configure()` methods that return `this`:

```
public class ChildViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IChild
{
    // IChild members...

    public ChildViewModel Configure(IScreen parent)
    {
        Parent = parent;
        return this;
    }
}

public class ParentViewModel : Screen
{
    public ChildViewModel Child { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialize()
    {
        Child = _viewModelFactory.Create<ChildViewModel>()
                                 .Configure(this);
    }
}
```

It should be possible to customise Caliburm.Micro's view model handling code to set the parent automatically, but I'm not clever enough with it yet to know how to do that, yet. :)