# Caliburn.Micro: moving between pages with Conductor: how can I call a parent class method or property from a child class?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, autofac, caliburn.micro, conductor

This is my main, parent class, ViewModel:

```cs
[AutofacRegisterType(PAGE_NAME, typeof(IMainPage), IsSingleInstance = false)]
public class MainPageViewModel : MainPageViewModelBase
{
    public const string PAGE_NAME = "MainPage";

    public MainPageChildsConductor ChildPages { get; private set; }

    public IMainPageChild ActiveChildPage
    {
        get { return ChildPages.ActiveItem; }
    }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        PageName = PAGE_NAME;
        DisplayName = PAGE_NAME;

        DisposeOnDeactivate = true;

        InitChildPages();
    }

    private void InitChildPages()
    {
        ChildPages = new MainPageChildsConductor();
        ChildPages.Parent = this;
        ChildPages.ConductWith(this);

        var trallchilds = TypeRegistry.GetItemsByType<IMainPageChild>();
        var trchilds = trallchilds.Where(p => p.AutoRegister != null && p.AutoRegister.Name.StartsWith(PAGE_NAME + ":")).ToList();

        var childs = new List<IMainPageChild>();
        foreach (var trchild in trchilds)
        {
            var child = trchild.CreateType<IMainPageChild>();
            childs.Add(child);
        }

        childs.Sort((a, b) => a.PageIndex.CompareTo(b.PageIndex));
        ChildPages.Items.AddRange(childs);

        ChildPages.ActivateWith(this);
        ChildPages.DeactivateWith(this);
    }
}
```

This is one of my child classes, ViewModel:

```cs
[AutofacRegisterType(PAGE_NAME, typeof(IMainPageChild), IsSingleInstance = false)]
public class Child1PageViewModel : MainPageChildViewModelBase
{
    public const string PAGE_NAME = "ChildPage:Child1Page";
    public const int PAGE_INDEX = 30;

    public Child1PageViewModel()
    {
        PageName = PAGE_NAME;
        DisplayName = "Child1";
        PageIndex = PAGE_INDEX;

        InitButtons();
        InitSummaryData();
    }
}
```

And this is the class that inherits the Caliburn.Micro class Conductor:

```cs
public class MainPageChildsConductor : Conductor<IMainPageChild>.Collection.OneActive
{
    public MainPageChildsConductor()
    {
    }

    public override void NotifyOfPropertyChange([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.NotifyOfPropertyChange(propertyName);

        if (Parent is INotifyPropertyChangedEx)
            ((INotifyPropertyChangedEx)Parent).Refresh();
    }
}
```

The question is: how can I call a method or property that exists in the parent page 'MainPageViewModel' from the child page 'Child1PageViewModel'???

Comment: I know how can I call a method or property that exists in a child class from the parent class, like this:


if (ActiveChildPage.PageName == "ChildPage:Child1Page")
{
 (Pages.ChildrenPageTabs.Child1PageViewModel)ActiveChildPage).DoShowClickedButton();
}

But I don't know how to do it the other way around - how to call a method or property that exists in the parent class from a child class? Does anybody have any idea how can I do it?

Comment: The parent class gives itself to the child class.

Comment: Does your child view model inherit from Screen or implement IScreen? This is needed by the child view model and only available when activated. See here for more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832780/caliburn-micro-ichild-parent-is-null-unless-activated-by-conductor

Answer (score 0):

Your child view needs to inherit from Screen and when activated in the parent view model, you obtain a reference to the child VM's Parent property via inheritance from Screen.

See this page in the documentation for more details:
[Screens, Conductors and Composition](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition).

This is how I do it in one of my projects:

```
public class MainViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive, IHandle<CreateNewGraphEvent>, IHandle<AddMeasurementsToGraphEvent>, IHandle<DeleteNamedGraphEvent>,
    IHandle<GraphRenamedEvent>, IHandle<AddDuplicateGraphEvent>
{
    private readonly TreeListViewModel _TreeView;
    private readonly StatusBarViewModel _StatusBar;
    private readonly IEventAggregator _Aggregator;
    private readonly ProgressDialogViewModel _Progress;

    public MainViewModel(IEventAggregator aggregator, TreeListViewModel treeView, StatusBarViewModel statusBar)
    {
        if (aggregator == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("aggregator");
        _Aggregator = aggregator;
        _Aggregator.Subscribe(this);

        if (statusBar == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("statusBar");
        _StatusBar = statusBar;

        if (treeView == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("treeView");
        _TreeView = treeView;
        this.Items.CollectionChanged += Items_CollectionChanged;
    }

    public void Handle(CreateNewGraphEvent message)
    {
        ChartViewModel document = IoC.Get<ChartViewModel>(message.SelectedGraphType.ToString());
        if (document == null) return;
        document.DisplayName = message.GraphName;
        document.CloseAction = this.CloseAction;
        document.SelectedGraphType = message.SelectedGraphType;
        ActivateItem(document);
    }
}

public class ChartViewModel : Screen, IHandle<MeasurementRenamedEvent>
{
    private readonly IEventAggregator _Aggregator;
    private readonly ISupportServices _Services;

    public ChartViewModel(IEventAggregator aggregator, ISupportServices services) : base(aggregator, services)
    {
        if (aggregator == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("aggregator");
        _Aggregator = aggregator;
        _Aggregator.Subscribe(this);

        if (services == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("services");
        _Services = services;
    }}
```

When ActivateItem item method is called in MainViewModel, the CihldViewModel is added to the Items collection in MainViewModel and activates the child VM, where you can then access MainViewModel through the this.Parent property in ChildViewModel.